# JPA: Store last update time in a separate table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I am working with jpa and hibernate and i'm trying to store the creation/update/deletion time for each item managed by JPA.

I need something like Hibernate Envers, but just store the last time, not all the revisions and I would like to store that data in a separate table (cause this data are not part of the item itself but belong to an optional syncronization process that need to know the last modify time for each item).

As now i can capture all events using jpa @EntityListeners, but now i don't know how to persist these information to a database table.
I would like to not define a item_history table entity, but generate and acces them at runtime  like envers does.

is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Hibernate interceptor to capture the DML operations over your entities and store the data you need in separated tables.

[Check this example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/.)

If you don't want to map a new entity to store your history records, execute a native SQL to copy your data or call a PL/SQL procedure. An example:

```
Table table = Entity.class.getAnnotation(Table.class);
String tableName = table.name();
Query query = session.createQuery("insert into " + table + "_HIST" +
            "SELECT * FROM " + table ;
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: As i said : i can capture all events using jpa @EntityListeners.
The problem is : would like to not define a item_history table entity